# Loading a storyboard from menuitem in appdata

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, storyboard, statusbar

This must be much simpler than I'm making it out to be.

I have a Main.storyboard that launches when app loads up.   I have a system menu where one of the menu items needs to load the storyboard dialog.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItemWithLength(-1)
    statusBarItem.menu = menu
    statusBarItem.title = "WP"


    var options = NSMenuItem(title: "Options ...", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
    var quit = NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: Selector("terminate:"), keyEquivalent: "q")

    menu.addItem(options)
    menu.addItem(quit)

}
```

The options variable "action" needs to load the storyboard.  Do I have access to it in the AppDelegate?

Comment: when you say "load the storyboard", do you mean that you want to load a NSWindowController (or a subclass) ***from*** the storyboard?

Comment: It's the NSWindowController from the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, it looks like your app is entirely a status bar app (with no window that appears when it launches?).

So basically you'll want to instantiate and then bring up the window. Maybe something like this?

in your "`applicationDidFinishLaunching`" function:

```
    var menuItem : NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
    menuItem.title = "Options ..."
    menuItem.action = Selector("bringUpOptionsWindow:")
    menuItem.target = self
    menuItem.keyEquivalent = ""
    menuItem.enabled = true
    menu.addItem(menuItem)

// ...
// and then later on
// ...

func bringUpOptionsWindow(sender : AnyObject)
{
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let myController = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("MyOptionsWindowController") as! NSWindowController

    myController.showWindow(sender)
}
```

Comment: Actually it kind of works.  It shows up and then disappears right away. Could the memory manager be cleaning it up?

Comment: If I make the controller an appdata member, it works!